# want to place part of php code somewhere else on page

Tags: php, authentication, content-management-system

I'm very new to php. I found some CMS like code for east text editing here on SO and now I'm trying to implement it on our micro site.
My problem is, that I want login error report to show on exact position on the page - just under the login button.
Can someone tell me how can I put that error report text whereever I want? I don't want to override it with CSS positioning.

In basic, I want to put that p class="error":

```
<?php
    if (empty($_POST) && isset($_GET['action'])) {
            $action = $_GET['action'];
            switch ($action) {
                case 'logout':
                    session_unset();
                    session_destroy();
                    break;
        }
    }
      if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
                $user = '';
                $pass = '';
                if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
                    $user = strtolower(trim($_POST['user']));
                    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
                    $errors = array();
                    if ($user == '' || $user != '1') {
                        $errors['user'] = '';
                    }
                    if ($pass == '' || $pass != '1') {
                        $errors['pass'] = '';
                    }
                    if (empty($errors)) {
                        $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
                    } else {
                        echo '<p class="error">Insert correct ';
                        if (isset($errors['user']))
                            echo 'name';
                        if (count($errors) == 2)
                            echo ' a ';
                        if (isset($errors['pass']))
                            echo 'password';
                        echo '.</p>', "\n";
                    }
                }
           }
    if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    ?>
```

somewhere else in the whole code of my page. Do I need to cut out something from that php code, or do I need to write new part of code for that?

Thank you for you help, Matej

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of just doing 'echo' all over the place, which means you get output at the place where the PHP code is embedded in the page, set some flags/message variables to output later.

e.g.

```
<?php

$errors = false;
$msgs = '';

if (....) {
   $errors = true;
   $msgs = "something dun gone wrong";
}
?>

... various bits of your html go here ...
<?php if ($errors) { echo $msgs; } ?>
... more html here ...
```